# Calculate the difference between two off64_t numbers C++

Tags: c++

I would like to allocate memory in order to read (whole) very large files (15-25 Gb) in my C++ program. I have used `off64_t` type to get the beginning and ending positions of the file that I want to read, which are obtained from my file using function `ftello64`. I would now like to get the difference between the two in a variable called size and then allocate this to a char array. However, and despite compiling successfully, my code doesn't work properly.
I tried `size = (off64_t)(end_of_mem-start_of_mem);` where `start_of_mem` and `end_of_mem` are both `off64_t` numbers but when I run my program the output is

```
Starting position in memory (start_of_mem):152757
Ending position in memory (end_of_mem):15808475159
Size: -1371546782
```

What variant type should I be using to get this right? Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: It's highly unlikeley that you can get 15Gb of free heap. You should look for memory-mapped files in your OS.

Comment: Please show small, compiling code that has the problem.

Comment: You need to show the data type for `size` and how you display the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing int down-casting from 64bit to 32bit side-effects.

Take a look at following experiment:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  int64_t int64 = 15808475159 - 152757;
  int32_t int32 = int64;

  std::cout << "int64_t: " << int64 << "\n";
  std::cout << "int32_t: " << int32 << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
int64_t: 15808322402
int32_t: -1371546782
```

Problem is the result of `15808475159 - 152757` is bigger than range of 32-bit integer. Thus due overflow it gets truncated (or mod 2^32). Then because its declared as signed 32-bit it apparently falls into the a negative range of interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for all comments and for the answer!

Comment: As other comments say, I am not sure if you can get 25GB memory allocated in one chunk, and solves your problem ultimately. But it surely explains why you are observing what you are.